# Hyperlink boxes not sized correctly in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

I'm having very weird behavior with hyperlinks in a tikzpicture.  Here's a code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=8em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=8em, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{rect2} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5.5em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=5.5em, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{anch} = [inner sep=0em, outer sep=0em]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

% Create a spacer to make sure box around link isn't too close to text.
\newcommand{\spacerrule}[3][0 em]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#2]{#1}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

% So the hyperlinks link to something.
\label{signedranktest}
\label{ranksumtest}

% Verify that the commands work outside of tikzpicture

\hyperref[signedranktest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}\spacerrule{.1 em}{1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test}\spacerrule{-.4 em}{1 em}}}
\vspace{1 em}

\hyperref[ranksumtest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}\spacerrule{.1 em}{1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}\spacerrule{-.4 em}{1 em}}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3 em]

\node (samp2) [rect] {2 groups};

\node (lev2b) [anch, below of=samp2]{};
\node (paired1) [rect, below left of=lev2b, xshift=-3 em, yshift=-1.5 em]{Paired/matched samples};
\node (indep1) [rect, below right of=lev2b, xshift=3 em, yshift=-1.5 em]{Independent samples};

\node (pairtest) [below of=paired1, yshift=-2 em, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[signedranktest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}\spacerrule{.1 em}{1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test}\spacerrule{-.4 em}{1 em}}}};

\node (indtest) [below of=indep1, yshift=-2 em, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[ranksumtest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}\spacerrule{.1 em}{1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}\spacerrule{-.4 em}{1 em}}}};

\draw [arrow] (samp2) -- (lev2b);
\draw [arrow] (lev2b) -| (paired1);
\draw [arrow] (lev2b) -| (indep1);
\draw [arrow] (paired1) -- (pairtest);
\draw [arrow] (indep1) -- (indtest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

When I run this, the box around "Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test" is mis-sized, with the program thinking it is only one line high instead of two.  The really weird thing is that if you comment out the line starting with "\node (pairtest)", then the "Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test" box is mis-sized in the same way as the other one used to be; and if you switch the order of the lines starting with "\node (pairtest)" and "\node (indtest)", then the WRST box is mis-sized and the WSRT box is correct!  So it seems it's always the first one it encounters that is mis-sized.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try removing `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`.  Then put `\centering` immediately after `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3 em]`.  Does that fix it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your code dates from the first versions of TikZ and is now deprecated.

The extra boxes you've added everywhere are disrupting TikZ's normal work. The easiest way here is to do everything with the new 3.0.1a's TikZ version and  without having to go through additional commands that complicate his work.

So, I deleted theses boxes and updated the code.

Thus, your personal macro `\spacerrule` is useless and to solve all your problems, just load the `positioning` library (read section 17.5.3 from page 229 of the manual 3.0.1a).

The `\tikzstyle` is depreciated in favor of the `\tikzset`.
For arrows, the library is now called `arrows.meta`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{rect/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=8em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=8em, text centered, draw=black},
        rect2/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5.5em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=5.5em, text centered, draw=black},
        anch/.style={inner sep=0em, outer sep=0em}
        }

% Create a spacer to make sure box around link isn't too close to text.
%\newcommand{\spacerrule}[3][0 em]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#2]{#1}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

% So the hyperlinks link to something.
\label{signedranktest}
\label{ranksumtest}

% Verify that the commands work outside of tikzpicture

\hyperref[signedranktest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test}}}
\vspace{1 em}

\hyperref[ranksumtest]{\parbox{9em}{\center\vspace{-1 em}%
\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3 em,>={Stealth}]

\node (samp2) [rect] {2 groups};

\node (lev2b) [anch, below of=samp2]{};
\node (paired1) [rect, below left=  of lev2b]{Paired/matched samples};
\node (indep1) [rect, below right= of lev2b]{Independent samples};


\node (pairtest) [below = of paired1, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[signedranktest]{\textbf{Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test}}};

\node (indtest) [below = of indep1, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[ranksumtest]{\parbox{9em}{\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}}}};

\draw [->] (samp2) -- (lev2b);
\draw [->] (lev2b) -| (paired1);
\draw [->] (lev2b) -| (indep1);
\draw [->] (paired1) -- (pairtest);
\draw [->] (indep1) -- (indtest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A deprecated version!  That didn't occur to me.  Thanks!  That being said, your code didn't quite work for me, although it did give me the starting point to fix everything.  Note, for example, that in your output, WRST is left-justified instead of centered.  Also, I explicitly want the red boxes around the hyperlinks that hyperref provides by default (in my setup, at least), and when I run your code as-is, the hyperlink box is around each line of WSRT in the normal way of hyperlinks with line breaks in them, instead of being a single box around the whole thing, which is what I want.

Comment: Here are the corrections I made: (1) put my spacing macro back in (because otherwise the red box touches the words inside, which I don't want); (2) Replaced "\center\vspace{-1 em} from my original code with "\centering"; (3) added "arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}" to the \tikzset command.  Those changes made everything work.  (Although I have no doubt there's a more elegant way to handle everything.)

Comment: With the code you gave in the question, there is no red box after compilation.  As for the fact that a text is justified on the left, it's because I forgot to delete the box you added `\parbox{9em}{\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}}` and which prevents TikZ from centering normally as it does with the other.

Comment: With TikZ, to separate the text from the sides of the box, simply use the `inner sep` key

Comment: AndréC: I appreciate your input, but in my version of TeX I get the red boxes.  I'm using MikTeX with the most current versions of all the packages and the default settings (other than what's changed in the posted code).  I don't know if you're using different settings or if your defaults are somehow different, but for some reason we're getting different results.  As I said, while your code didn't work directly for me, you gave me the hint I needed to fix things, so thanks!  When I'm back on my other computer, I'll post the code that I ended up with.

Comment: @bad_platypus On the code you gave in the question, there is no red color, I did a search for the keyword `red` and this word is not there. You must have made a mistake when copying. I also use the latest version of MikTeX, which I update daily.

Comment: From the hyperref documentation (November 2012 version, Section 3.6), it looks like the reason I'm getting the boxes is because I'm going straight to PDF (the format I need); are you using Postscript or DVI?  The argument "linkbordercolor=" (which is PDF-specific) in the hyperref call lets you change this; I tried it and can change the color to blue, for example.

Comment: @bad_platypus I compile with pdfLaTeX

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's the final code that worked for me; thanks to AndréC for pointing me in the right direction.  I removed my spacing macro from the WRST box to illustrate why I used it.  For those of you not following our comment thread, you need to create a PDF to see the boxes around the links.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref} % Makes blue box in PDF
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{rect/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=8em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=8em, text centered, draw=black},
        rect2/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5.5em,%
minimum height=3em, text width=5.5em, text centered, draw=black},
        anch/.style={inner sep=0em, outer sep=0em}
        }

% Create a spacer to make sure box around link in PDF isn't too close to text.
\newcommand{\spacerrule}[3][0 em]{\textcolor{white}{\rule[#2]{#1}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

% So the hyperlinks link to something.
\label{signedranktest}
\label{ranksumtest}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3 em,>={Stealth}]

\node (samp2) [rect] {2 groups};

\node (lev2b) [anch, below of=samp2]{};
\node (paired1) [rect, below left=  of lev2b]{Paired/matched samples};
\node (indep1) [rect, below right= of lev2b]{Independent samples};

% With spacing macro:

\node (pairtest) [below = of paired1, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[signedranktest]{\parbox{9em}{\centering\spacerrule{.1 em}{1 em}\textbf{Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test}\spacerrule{-.4 em}{1 em}}}};

% Without spacing macro:

\node (indtest) [below = of indep1, text width=9em, text centered]%
{\hyperref[ranksumtest]{\parbox{9em}{\centering\textbf{Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test}}}};

\draw [->] (samp2) -- (lev2b);
\draw [->] (lev2b) -| (paired1);
\draw [->] (lev2b) -| (indep1);
\draw [->] (paired1) -- (pairtest);
\draw [->] (indep1) -- (indtest);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```